# set chunk path a with webpack and react lazy code splitting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm using react lazy for route based code splitting as described here: https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#route-based-code-splitting

My routes file looks like this:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';

const APage = lazy(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "APage" */ '../pages/APage'));
const BPage = lazy(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "BPage" */ '../pages/BPage'));

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/products/a" component={APage}/>
        <Route exact path="/products/b" component={BPage}/>
      </Switch>
    </Suspense>
  </Router>
);
```

When I compile the app it correctly generates 4 JS chunks:

```
app.js
APage.js
BPage.js
APage~BPage.js
```

however when I navigate to this path: `/products/a`, I get these load errors because my component files are located in the root, not in a 'products' folder:

```
http://localhost.com:3000/products/APage~BPage.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost.com:3000/products/APage.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

**How can I configure webpack/react to load components from the root of my site and/or from an external CDN?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in webpack 's module add output values like this :

```
    output: {
      publicPath: '/',
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'root'),
    }
```

Comment: cool looks like it works for local paths and to change the domain for a CDN

Comment: I too had got stuck at this issue. Glad it was of help. 